# How to pause running countdown with button to redirect page?

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

Already i got this code in javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var count = 20; // Timer
  var redirect = "https://www.instagram.com/"; // Target URL

  function countDown() {
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer"); // Timer ID
    if (count > 0) {
      count--;
      timer.innerHTML = "przekieruje cię za " + count + " sekund."; // Timer Message
      setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);
    } else {
      window.location.href = redirect;
    }
  }
</script>
```

I would like to place button with pause in my html site - it will works like 'if i press the button while countdown is running it will be stopped, but if i click again it will resume'. I've tried to put clearInterval in code but it didn't work. I'm really an amateur when it comes to javascript.

Comment: Since you are using _timeout_, then you must use _clearTimeout_ instead of _clearInterval_

Answer (score -1):

Nothing special

```js
(async()=>{
    const timer = document.getElementById('timer');

    let timerId;
    let tf = false;
    let k = 7;

    const plusplus = async()=>{
        timer.innerHTML = k + ' dancing cows left';
        if(k < 1)clearInterval(timerId);
        else k--;
    };

    plusplus();
    timerId = setInterval(plusplus, 1000);
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if(!tf)clearInterval(timerId);
        else timerId = setInterval(plusplus, 1000);
        tf = !tf;
    });
})();
```

```html
<button id="button">stop / resume</button>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: My friend, i can't see redirect in this script after countdown had reaches 0, but thank you for response!

Comment: @Zimnyjestem `if(k < 1)clearInterval(timerId);` this line